# Create computed property dependent on variables within onMounted() lifecycle hook

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a component that needs to calculate some values using the DOM, and so I have the `onMounted()` lifecycle hook. In `onMounted()` I calculate some values (technically, they're computed properties) dependent on DOM elements.

I then use the values found in another computed property, `leftOffset`. I need to use `leftOffset` in `template` (it changes some CSS, not really relevant).

Below is my `setup()`:

```
setup() {
    let showContent = ref(false);
    
    let windowWidth = ref(null);
    let contentHider = ref(null);

    let contentHiderXPos ;
    let contentHiderWidth ;
    let leftWidth;

    onMounted(() => {
        // The DOM element will be assigned to the ref after initial render
        windowWidth = ref(window.innerWidth);

        contentHiderXPos = computed(() => contentHider.value.getBoundingClientRect().left);
        contentHiderWidth = computed(() => contentHider.value.getBoundingClientRect().width);
        leftWidth = computed(() => contentHiderXPos.value + contentHiderWidth.value);
    });

    let leftOffset = computed(() => {
        return -(windowWidth.value - leftWidth.value)
    });

    return {
        contentHider,
        leftOffset,
    }
```

`contentHider` references a the DOM element of one of the divs defined in `template`.

My problem that `leftOffest.value` is undefined, because it tries to access `windowWidth.value` and `leftWidth.value`, which are also undefined. I've also tried putting `leftOffset` inside `onMounted()`, but then I can't access it from `template` (it's undefined).

How can I re-structure my code so that `leftOffset` can both be accessed from `template` and can also access the values found in `onMounted()`?

I've searched online, but couldn't find anything specific to the composition API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of the `ref` is wrong. Follow the comments in the below snippet.

Also this is assuming that you do not want the window.innerwidth to be reactive.

```
// dont create another ref => you are trying to assign a new object here, thus breaking the reactivity
// windowWidth = ref(window.innerWidth);
// do this instead
windowWidth.value = window.innerWidth
```

If you want the `innerWidth` to be reactive, you have to use the native event listener like this;

```
const windowWidth = ref(window.innerWidth)
onMounted(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {windowWidth.value = window.innerWidth} )
})
onUnmounted(() => {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', () => {windowWidth.value = window.innerWidth})
})
```

Comment: If I made `windowWidth` a computed property, would I still need to add event listeners to the window to make `innerWidth` reactive?

Comment: Yes, window properties are not reactive in Vue

Comment: what's the point of removing the event listener?

Comment: Because if the component is remounted then another event listener will be registered and both listeners will get executed. It’s not efficient and could be error prone too.

Comment: ohh ok, thanks. In `removeEventListener()` you've also put the arrow function, `() => {windowWidth.value = window.innerWidth}`. I don't have much experience with event listeners, but is this valid?

Comment: That’s ok. You need to tell which function to remove from the registered event listeners.